# Regular Expression for email to check repetitive characters

Tags: regex, ng-pattern

I'm validating email address with regular expression. I would like to test for a following conditions:

**minimum of 3 characters in name, symbol @, minimum 3 characters in first part of domain, a dot,no more than 3 repetitive characters**

I tried this regular expression and it's working fine for all cases except last one.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}\@[A-Za-z0-9.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/
```

It's not checking for repetitive character(any character) after dot(.)

Not Ok: test@test.**ccccom**, test@test.coooom

Ok : test@test.com

Don't know what is wrong with last portion of my RE.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a piece of advice: drop the *"minimum 3 characters in first part of domain"* requirement. There are valid domain names with less than 3 characters (an example would be wp.pl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{3})[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}\@[A-Za-z0-9-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

Changes made:

`(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{3})` - This is a negative lookahead that makes sure that none of the characters repeat more than thrice in a row.

The rest of the regex is same as it is, except for the removal of the `.` from the second character class.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yR8yG1/1)

---

If you want to disallow repeated characters after the last `.`, then you could use the following instead:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}\@[A-Za-z0-9-]{3,}\.(?!([A-Za-z0-9])\1{3})[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yR8yG1/4)

Comment: @Murali, Is it possible to check repetitive characters only after a dot(.) in email address at last part?

Comment: @Chirag:  Sure, just move the negative lookahead to after the `.`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This won't allow more than three repeated characters after the last dot,

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}\@[A-Za-z0-9.-]{3,}\.(?:(?!(.)\1{3})[a-zA-Z]){2,4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yR8yG1/3)